# Rolling back to an older version of a firebase function (google cloud function)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, rollback

I am trying to find an easy way to roll back to a/the previous version of my firebase function(google cloud function), in case the new release of this firebase function creates a problem to the deployed system.

The way I deploy the functions is via firebase cli (firebase deploy --only functions) and not gcloud cli.

Is there an easy way to roll back to the previous version of the function?

Answer (score 14):

There is currently no rollback feature.  You will have to deploy the function again using the source code that you want to have in its place.  To make this easier on themselves, developers typically tag their code in source control after a deploy, so that it's easy to check out a specific version of the code to roll back later.

Comment: Thanks for your response!